# iOS - hidden accessory becomes visible after orientation change

Tags: ios7, uitextfield, uiinterfaceorientation

In my case I'm using a `UITextField` as the accessory that I don't need to show all the time. I've confirmed the change happens *after* the orientation notification events fire. I guess a hack would be to resize the accessory to zero height, but I'm reticent to do this.

Wondering if anyone has encountered this and found a solution?

Have entered a bug report and provided a sample project. For those with higher privileges, it is searchable on bugreport.apple.com as ID 16771757. I have also copied it to a Dropbox account accessible as https://www.dropbox.com/s/o28vo04ig3yhgz6/ID16771757.zip.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have tried changing the accessory to zero height, causes numerous other bugs including "bogus layer size" warnings and exceptions.

Comment: Looks like @Visput has the correct solution, but if you didn't wish to override methods you could use `setAlpha` in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` on the view controller.

Comment: @WilliamGeorge - thank you. I was actually inspired by your solution to use `if ([accessoryView isHidden]) [accessoryView setAlpha: 0.0f];` in `didRotate...`, and in the code that calls `becomefirstResponder` set alpha to 1. No new classes, no overriding methods, will still work if Apple fixes the bug, no measuring heights, all around good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS calls such methods for input accessory view instance:

1. `[inputAccessoryView setAlpha:1];` when owner of accessory view becomes first responder (internal method call  `-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) executeTransition:]`);
2. `[inputAccessoryView setHidden:NO];` when interface rotation finished (internal method call `-[UIPeripheralHost finishRotationOfKeyboard:]`);

That's why your input accessory view becomes visible after interface rotation event.

Solution depends on behaviour that you expect:
Let's imagine that `input accessory view height = 44` ->
Now you hide input accessory view and set owner as first responder:
If you expect `inputAccessoryView.frame.size.height equals 0` then solution for hiding input accessory view is set it to nil: `inputAccessoryView = nil`;

If you expect `inputAccessoryView.frame.size.height equals 44` then solution for hiding input accessory view is override `setHidden:` method for it:

```
- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    [super setHidden:self.customIsHiddenFlag];
}
```

where `customIsHiddenFlag` property that you need use for implementing logic of showing/hiding accessory view;

or override `setAlpha:` method:

```
- (void)setAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    [super setAlpha:(self.customIsHiddenFlag ? 0 : 1)];
}
```

These solutions work for iOS 7.

For iOS 6 you could use your base solution `inputAccessoryView.hidden = YES` and it works because iOS doesn't call `setHidden:NO` automatically when interface rotation is fired.

It seems that you are right and it's a bug cause of different behaviour on iOS6 and iOS7. If Apple wants to show input accessory view forcedly then they should call `setHidden:NO` not only after interface rotation but also when owner becomes first responder.

Comment: I like the idea overriding `setHidden`. I will wait until I test the latest seed to see if it is fixed already before implementing the workaround.

Comment: As a general rule, it is not recommended to fight with the framework which overriding setHidden is. The separation of responsibilities is pretty clear here: when you hand in a view to the framework you *expect* its parameters to be adjusted as necessary, including layout and visibility. A solution that respects framework's behaviour with less code is to use a transparent view as accessory view and lay out any custom view inside of it (please refer to the answer I posted).

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's documentation on `inputAccessoryView`:

> … ***Subclasses*** that want to attach custom controls to either a system-supplied input view (such as the keyboard) or a custom input view (one you provide in the inputView property) ***should redeclare this property as readwrite*** and use it to manage their custom accessory view. [emphasis mine]

So the correct way to hide the accessory view would be redeclaring the property as readwrite:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) UIView *inputAccessoryView;
```

removing the accessory view from superview and setting the property to nil when appropriate:

```
- (IBAction)hideAccessoryView:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.inputAccessoryView removeFromSuperview];
    self.inputAccessoryView = nil;
}
```

This is correct with regard to the docs but if you look at the view hierarchy, there's a UIPeripheralHostView (UIKit private class) that does not change its size. This most likely means that throwing out the accessory view will not be reflected by keyboard size — it'll stay the same. Keep this in mind if you plan to calculate any offsets to adjust to on-screen keyboard.

That said, the best way for you to move forward might be using a completely transparent view as the accessory view and have your custom view (UITextField in this case) as a subview. That way you will get both complete control over your custom view and consistent behaviour of your app on current and future versions of iOS.

*Edit:*

Here's a screenshot showing a slightly modified version of your bug report app with UIPeripheralHostView highlighted:

[image: Reveal screenshot]

You can see how size of the view stays the same after the accessory view has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an accessory view, you "pass" it to the system for layout. It is more than likely, when Apple performs layout on the keyboard view, it also layouts the accessory view and sets it to visible. Setting the accessory as hidden can also have other side effects, such as the keyboard height being incorrectly calculated, thus causing incorrect inset calculation.

From my experience, it is best to remove the accessory and add it again when necessary. Resizing the accessory view will cause other issues related to keyboard size. If you want to hide and show quickly, subclass the view that includes the accessory view, and implement internally the setting and removing of accessory view.

Comment: The protocol seems to provide only the means to pass the view for layout. There doesn't seem to be any way to explicitly set it, e.g. `[self setInputAccessoryView:nil]`.

Comment: That's right, but you can implement a method called `setAccessoryViewHidden:(BOOL)hidden` which sets it or sets it to nil according to `hidden`. Setting it to `nil` is the only correct option to have a hidden accessory view. You can always retain it if you wish to have to used later.

Comment: My first theory was the same as Leo's but unfortunately that doesn't work. Apparently, Apple does not support live removing of input accessory view. They would have to introduce extra complexity with changes of the keyboard size.

Comment: @Leonty Actually it works. I have a keyboard extension in my app which is added and removed dynamically. The framework fades the accessory in and out and sends a notification that the keyboard frame changed.

Comment: @LeoNatan are you sure you didn't write this logic yourself? I've checked with custom responder and with UITextView on iOS 6.1. and 7.1 — setting `inputAccessoryView` to nil does not remove the view immediately. I wonder what I'm missing!

Comment: @LeontyDeriglazov Actually, I am using a webview with my accessory (we have a rich HTML editing view using a webview).